# Error receiving broadcast Intent in my Bluetooth-program

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, action, broadcast

I use this piece of code to check if my bluetooth finds my 'friends phone', problem is that sometimes when I run it, I get an 'Error receiving broadcast Intent'. It says that it has problems with the 'BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)'
I researched some other questions on stackoverflow, where someone suggested using 'intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);' which I tried, but it seems to have no effect... Anyone got an idea why this doesn't work for me or got an idea on how to fix it?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (bluetoothDevice.getName().equals("friends phone"))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the BL device discovery in this way and works reliably:

Define these in your Activity:

```
private final IntentFilter deviceFoundFilter = new IntentFilter();
private final BroadcastReceiver deviceFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        String name = device.getName();
        String address = device.getAddress();
        int bondState = device.getBondState();

        if (bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
            deviceListAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

    }
};
```

and let's say in onCreate method or any other init-like method add the following rows:

```
    deviceFoundFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(deviceFoundReceiver, deviceFoundFilter);
```

Hope it helps.